# Pizza crust mix for pizza with cast iron pan?

Tags: pizza, cast-iron

I bought this "*Mantita's italiano* Crispy Pizza Crust Mix", but I own no pizza pan. All I have is a 8 inch wide, ~2inch deep, round "Lodge" cast iron pan I have never used before.

I want to make a deep dish pizza with it. How much of the crust mix should I use in the pan?
The crust mix says its for a 12inch pizza and requires 1/2 a cup of hot water.

Comment: @Catija         It is 8 inch wide, sorry I was not thinking.

Comment: @Catija          Its round sorry

Comment: It's a little less than half the size.

Comment: @Catija         So then I should be using 1/2 of the mix for a pizza in this cast iron?

Comment: Hope it works out for you! Make sure to oil the pan really well!

Comment: By the way, if the pizza crust is labeled "crispy" does that mean it's designed to be thin crust? Or is it deep dish too?

Comment: Be sure to check out what [Serious Eats](http://slice.seriouseats.com/archives/2013/01/the-pizza-lab-the-worlds-easiest-pizza-no-knead-no-stretch-pan-pizza.html) has to say. Also look at this: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43430/is-our-oven-at-work-powerful-enough-to-bake-pizza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **bottom** of the 8" pan is a bit less than half the size.

For a 2" **deep-dish**, there's a 2-inch high (if you take it to the top) 8π circumferential strip for another 16π, and presumably the 12" dough is for a flat pizza. At 32π .vs. 36π I'd do the whole box, unless your deep dish isn't really all that deep.

I'm also a bit concerned about  the "never used" cast iron pan needing some seasoning, but perhaps it's "lodge logic" pre-seasoned.

Answer (score 2):

So this takes a little bit of math.

You've got enough dough for a 12-inch diameter pizza.

The area is π6^2 = 36π.  You don't actually have to do the rest of the math.

You have a pan that is 8-inches in diameter.

The area is π4^2 = 16π

To find the difference, divide 16π/36π and you get .44 (the π cancels out), which is a little less than half. For simplicity, I recommend making half of the box.

Be sure to use half of everything, particularly the water, so if it calls for 1/2 cup of water, use only 1/4 cup.